# How does Google Fonts react with HTML in Outlook 2013?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, outlook

I'm trying to create a responsive email template for Outlook 2013, everything works well except the fonts. I'm using fonts from Google fonts, and I'm loading them like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm not sure if it fails since Outlook 2013 can't load media queries on my internal CSS level, or if its unable to load fonts from Google Fonts.

Any thoughts?

Comment: try downloading the css from google fonts and manually adding it to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook doesn't support web fonts. So you need a fallback font for Outlook like an Arial or Times New Romans things.

```html
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
body, table, th, td {font-family: Arial !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: And a list of good web safe fonts here that most computers have: http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html